# Profile mode detection not working in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In ionic app how can I detect profile modes like `vibrate,normal,silent`..in both android and ios platform?

I have also tried this..

```
plugins.ringerMode.getRingerMode(function(ringerMode) {
      console.log("The current ringerMode is:" + ringerMode);
});
```

but not get succeed..
specially for ios devices v.10+ Is there any solution for that?
please help..